# Line following robot in outdoor condition with intel sealsense d415

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, intel, contour

I am working on making a line following robot using Opencv and am using nvidia realsense d415 depth camera for image capturing.I am using cv2.findcontours and taking the max contour as the line and then working on that. the problem is along with detecting the main line , the code is also detecting random contours, like when I capture empty space on ground, it considers the whole frame as one contour. It is also picking up random objects as contour. Is there a way to detect just the black line? and no other object as contour?

Code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2) 
ret,frame = cap.read()
frame = frame[0:800,0:1800]
value = 80 #whatever value you want to add
cv2.add(frame[:,:,2], value, frame[:,:,2])
img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
_,threshold = cv2.threshold(img,60,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
mask = cv2.erode(threshold, None, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),1,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
max_c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(img, max_c, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

[image: code]

[image: camera image after processing using given code in above img]

[Image with object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvXEp.png)

Comment: can _you_ see anything in that picture? -- please review [ask]. no pictures of text.

Comment: Please share the code instead of its photo

Comment: can you show what you have tried (with code) and what does not work?

Comment: Sorry for the code issue, am editing the post. The image above is of the ground. (with no objects) Attaching another image.